# Jquery animation stuck on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have written a note app using Jquery but the container is stuck on load, how i can fix this bug ?
Demo : http://sallibert.com/apps/notes/notes.php
The html (simplified):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="contentWrapper">
        <div id="ntes_left_side">**Notes list and add one**</div>

        <div id="ntes_right_side">**Note content and back**</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
$(document).on('click','#ntesliste li', function(evt) {
$('#contentWrapper').animate({"left": "320px"}, "fast");    
    $('#zonote').focusout();
    fns.textAreaPopulate(+$(this).data('id'),this); 
});
$(document).on('click', '#retrlste', function() {
$('#contentWrapper').animate({"left": "0px"}, "fast");
});
$(document).on('click', '#compteurnte #ajouternote', function() {
$('#contentWrapper').animate({"left": "320px"}, "fast");
    fns.addNewNote();
});
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width:320px;
    height:480px;
    overflow:hidden;}

#contentWrapper{
    width:640px;
    height: 480px;
   float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#ntes_left_side, #ntes_right_side{
    width:320px;
    height: 480px;
    position:absolute;
}
#ntes_right_side{
    left:0px;
}
#ntes_right_side{
    left:320px;
}
```

Comment: The demo isn't loading at all so that seems like a server issue to me. Also give some more description of the exact problem you are attempting to solve. Lastly use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dryp5/)

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle where there is no bug: http://jsfiddle.net/zorgeclair/yaeU4/2/ The problem is that the container is not at the good place on load.

Comment: What do you mean, but not at a good place?

Comment: The previous fiddle were simplified. Here is, the full page, the js are in external links: http://jsfiddle.net/zorgeclair/pfdc4/

Comment: The error come from that i have a .focus() on the right side, which break the animation.
I must use something like this:

    while ($('contentWrapper').css('width') === '320px') {
    .....
    };

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.